# How to assign value to Richtextbox of CKEditor?

Tags: javascript, c#, ckeditor

I am using CKEditor richtexbox, I want to assign some value to that textbox through javascript but couldn't achieved.Tried below ways.
setData() 
insertHtml() 
insertText() 
I am getting Javascript error as "Object doesn't support property or method setData".
Below is html of richtextbox

```js
CKEDITOR.instances["#<%=txtrecoveryactivity.ClientID%>"].setData("<b>Demo</b> Title")
```

```html
<CKEditor:CKEditorControl ID="txtrecoveryactivity" BasePath="~/ckeditor" runat="server"></CKEditor:CKEditorControl>
```

Comment: Use comment blocks instead of code snippets for code.  Dear SO, there needs to be a better way to warn users about this - I see it all too often.

Comment: it is because, CKEDITOR.instances["#<%=txtrecoveryactivity.ClientID%>"] isn't returning you editor instance

Comment: and for that there could be two reasons, you are not passing correct ckeditor id, or this code is executed before ckeditor instance generated

Comment: @ParagBhayani
This code is executed after the ckeditor gets generated and I am getting correct instance .Do I need to add any JS file ?

Comment: if you do console.log(CKEDITOR.instances["#<%=txtrecoveryactivity.ClientID%>"]), what do you get? Would you create jsfiddle for this?

Answer (score 1):

Here from your error it looks like you are not getting correct instance of the editor, that is why it showing that "Object doesn't support property or method setData".

So for that there could be two cases:

1. you are not passing correct ckeditor id in `CKEDITOR.instances["#<%=txtrecoveryactivity.ClientID%>"]`
2. this code is executed before ckeditor instance created

Comment: It's worked.It was just semi-colon missing at end.Thank you